# How to determine position (x,y) relative to the page of every character inside spans through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

This is as simple as I can get.

I will have several spans randomly positioned on the screen through something like:

```
 $(".hidden:first").css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+((0.5-Math.random())*40)+'deg)'); 
 $(".hidden:first").animate({
    left: '+=' + (((screen.width-800-224)/2) + Math.random()*800),
    top: '+=' + (50+Math.random()*600)
  } [...]
```

and later on I would like to iterate through every char of every of those elements (that are randomly position and have random rotation), and I would need to discover the (x,y) position of every character on the screen so I can colorize it, forming certain draws according to certain functions.

Is this easily achievable? Remembering that I want the (x,y) position of each -character- of a span, not (x,y) of the span itself. I am really inexperienced at javascript.

EDIT: Answering my own question:
I currently managed to do what I needed by wrapping every single letter inside a `<span>` and later accessing its `.offset().left` and `.offset().top` through jquery. Is it that bad? :P

Thanks.
Fernando.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might get you started http://jsfiddle.net/QgRWk/

Comment: This wont work if the text has any styling IE <span>Hello <b>World</b></span> wont return the correct location of World